# Can’t make a true overlay with tikz, and noto font make it even worse

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, fonts, overlays

I wanted to create a highlight mechanism between slides. However, the highlight moves my element, even if I use in tikz `overlay`, or if I manually redefine the bounding box. Without the noto font, the baseline is just poorly aligned, but with the noto font the whole line moves:

Compare [image] and [image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\RequirePackage[sfdefault]{noto}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \def\myHighlight#1{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base)]%
      \node[fill=green,inner sep=0pt](a){#1};%
      \only<3->{\begin{scope}[overlay]
          \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \node[rounded corners,fill=green,fit=(a),inner sep=1pt](a){};%          
          \end{pgfonlayer}
        \end{scope}}
      \useasboundingbox (a.north east) rectangle (a.south west);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
  \begin{itemize}
  \item [\only<1>{Hello}\only<2->{\myHighlight{Hello}}] BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla
  \item [\only<1>{Hello}\only<2->{\myHighlight{Hello}}] BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla
  \item [\only<1>{Hello}\only<2->{\myHighlight{Hello}}] BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla
  \item [\only<1>{Hello}\only<2->{\myHighlight{Hello}}] BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla
  \item [\only<1>{Hello}\only<2->{\myHighlight{Hello}}] BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla
  \item [\only<1>{Hello}\only<2->{\myHighlight{Hello}}] BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla
  \item [\only<1>{Hello}\only<2->{\myHighlight{Hello}}] BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've reused the node name `a`, meaning that the `\useasboundingbox` is picking up the highlighting node rather than the text node.  Either give it a different name, or don't name it at all.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/685231/86}
\RequirePackage[sfdefault]{noto}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \def\myHighlight#1{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base)]%
      \node[fill=green,inner sep=0pt](a){#1};%
      \only<3->{\begin{scope}[overlay]
          \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \node[rounded corners,fill=green,fit=(a),inner sep=1pt](b){};% <-- node name change here
          \end{pgfonlayer}
        \end{scope}}
      \useasboundingbox (a.north east) rectangle (a.south west);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
  \begin{itemize}
  \item [\only<1>{Hello}\only<2->{\myHighlight{Hello}}] BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla
  \item [\only<1>{Hello}\only<2->{\myHighlight{Hello}}] BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla
  \item [\only<1>{Hello}\only<2->{\myHighlight{Hello}}] BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla
  \item [\only<1>{Hello}\only<2->{\myHighlight{Hello}}] BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla
  \item [\only<1>{Hello}\only<2->{\myHighlight{Hello}}] BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla
  \item [\only<1>{Hello}\only<2->{\myHighlight{Hello}}] BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla
  \item [\only<1>{Hello}\only<2->{\myHighlight{Hello}}] BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlabla Blabla
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Ohh good job, stupid copy/paste ^^

Comment: @tobiasBora Happens so often! Sometimes it really needs another pair of eyes on it to see what's causing the problem - happy to provide that pair of eyes this time!